# Neo4j After Deployment access

Tags: kubernetes, neo4j, cypher, kubectl

I am trying to deploy neo4j in k8, when i try and use port forward, i am able to access the cypher-shell along with neo4j browser in localhost but if I expose my service in k8 and try to access it via bolt(neo4j browser), i am getting an error

`ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser...`

Any idea how can i access the bolt port via neo4j browser without forwarding port to localhost

Comment: may be you have exposed service with https port and certificate issue.

Comment: thanks for replying, do you have a docker sample or something which is working

Comment: or any example how an i solve this, i am totally new to this